# How to LINQ in three collections?

Tags: c#, linq

I have three collections: CandidateList, GroupList, and PositionList. 
I wanna try to find out if there is a single candidate in a certain position as well as if there is a candidate on that particular group with that position.
It is like this:

```
candidateList = RetrieveCandidates();
groupList = RetrieveGroups();
positionList = RetrievePositions();

//first I loop through the candidates if there is at 
//least 1 candidate per position, INCLUDING THE INDEPENDENT CANDIDATES.


foreach (var pos in positionList)
{
    bool exists = candidateList.Any(x => x.PositionId == pos.PositionId)

    if(!exists)
    {
        //throw exception
    }

}

//then I loop through the groups if there is at least 1 candidate per position. 
//This will make sure that all positions for each group has a member.

foreach (var grp in groupList)
{
    foreach (var pos in positionList)
    {
        bool exists = candidateList.Any(x => x.PositionId == pos.PositionId && x.GroupId == grp.GroupId)

        if(!exists)
        {
            //throw exception
        }
    }
}
```

is there a way that I could simplify the code? preferably LINQ

EDIT: I forgot to mention about the Candidates who are Independent (candidate.CandidateId == 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first check can be reduced to :

```
var exists = positionList.All(p=> candidateList.Any(c=>c.PositionId == p.PositionId));
```

From there we can create your second check as

```
exists = groups.All(
                g =>positionList.All(
                     p=> candidateList.Any(
                          c=>c.PositionId == p.PositionId && c.GroupId == g.GroupId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
candidateList.Where(c=>positionList.Any(pos=>pos.PositionId == c.PositionId) 
        && groupList.Any(g=>g.GroupId == c.GroupId))
```

Will filter the candidates who has at least one position and group from those two lists.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't need the first statement if the second statement is true**, if there is **at least one candidate per group** with a position then there is **at least one candidate has the position**, so you just need to Linq-ify your second statement

```
positionList.All(pos=>
        groupList.All(grp=>
           canidateList.Any(can=> can.PositionId==pos.PositionId 
                                  && can.GroupId == grp.GroupId)));
```

However, see you are also doing exceptions for the two different cases so you could make an anonymous object that selects the groups that don't have matches and check the candidates as well

```
var result = 
    positionList.Select(pos=>new { 
        Position = pos,
        DoesNotHaveOneCanidate = 
            !canidateList.Any(can=> can.PositionId==pos.PositionId), 
        GroupsMissing = 
            groupList.Where(grp=>
                !canidateList.Any(can=> can.PositionId==pos.PositionId 
                                     && can.GroupId == grp.GroupId)
           ) 
    });
```